is it possible to solve the problem of having the same number of rows of input and output data in the user-defined Pandas UDF function in Flink?
I have a Flink task that reads data from Kafka topic,
translates it to Flink Table. Next, using map, it sends data to the user
-defined main_udf function wrapped with the Pandas UDF decorator. In main, the received
The pandas dataframe is transformed and processed with data decoding and
at the output we get a new pandas dataframe with new fields and number of rows.
But I get a logical error: AssertionError: The result length '110' of Pandas AND 'main_udf' is not equal to the input length '796'
How can this be circumvented? I need to work with pandas dataframe specifically
because I have a complex data processing logic. If anything, then I need to write the data to Click House.
def setup_packages_pipeline(st_env: StreamTableEnvironment, app_conf: AppConfig) -> Tuple[Table, str]:
  
    src_tname = create_trn_consumer(
        st_env,
        app_conf.kafka_conf,
        app_conf.input_conf,
        app_conf.group_id_prefix,
    )
   
    tbl = st_env.from_path(src_tname)
    log.warning("STARTING_TO_LOG_SCHEMA...")
    schema_str = tbl.explain()
    log.warning(f"TABLE_SCHEMA: {schema_str}")


    messages = tbl.filter(
        and_(
            col("rrrr") == "top",
            col("protocol") == "mining",
        )
    )

  
    messages.print_schema()

  
    packages = messages.map(main_udf)

    log.warning(f"PACKAGES: {packages}")

    tname = setup_click_sink(st_env, app_conf.click, TRAFFIC_PACKAGE_DATA_TYPE)

    return tname, packages




@udf(result_type=TRAFFIC_PACKAGE_DATA_TYPE, func_type="pandas")
def main_udf(df):
    log.info(f"First_data: {len(df)} строк")

    packages = main_function(df)

    log.info(f"Second_data: {len(packages)} строк")

    # Проверка корректности декодирования (пример)
    if packages.isnull().values.any():
        log.error("Nan_values_second!")
        raise ValueError("Nan_values_second")

    return packages


Clickhouse has a native kafka ingestor, so pandas wouldn't be necessary. You could write back to a new kafka topic
